# sql запросы на добавление товара в WooCommerce

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Народ привет!Подскажите какие sql запросы использует WooCommerce для полного добавления одного товара(с картинкой).Или есть ли способ отследить какие запросы прилетают к mysql от wordpress?

Comment: Вам это зачем? Там не один запрос, а несколько, в разные таблицы. Не лезьте в базу руками. Вы только все поломаете. Учите функции WC или REST API WC, в зависимости от того, как планируете взаимодействовать.

Comment: Понял.Спасибо.Буду копать REST API.